# ID of a created object always equal zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating web application that has to have the functionality to create Objects (their id, name, and a list of objects it is related to). Every time I create a new object its id is equal to zero? What is the best way to fix this?

my controller:

```
 // GET: Foo/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            return View();
        }

        // POST: Foo/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Foo foo)
        {
            try
            {
                var list = (List<Foo>)Session["list_foo"];
                if (list != null)
                {
                    list.Add(foo);

                }
                else
                {
                    list = new List<Foo>();
                    list.Add(foo);
                }

                Session["list_foo"] = list;

                return RedirectToAction("List");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
public ActionResult List()
        {
            var model = Session["list_foo"];
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Don't you supposed to save the created object to some database? The normal way is that the Id is generated from the database when a new row is inserted.

Comment: I don't see you creating an object here at all...

Answer (score 0):

> Every time I create a new object its id is equal to zero? What is the
>   best way to fix this?

This is reasonable, because each time you create a new object, you don't update it's id. Specifically, as I can suppose the id would be an `int`, when you GET the form and then POST it the id of the model you POST would be 0, since the default value of `int` is 0. When you POST you add the newly created object to a list. You don't store it in a database, retrieve the corresponding id and then update the id of the obect. That's why the `id` would be always 0.

Futhermore, I think that the GET should be like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{ 
    var model = new Foo();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply. What should I do to have each and every id be different than the Foo's I previously added?

Comment: your model class should have 
~~~
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
~~~
for the identity

Answer (score 0):

this is what your HttpPost Create Controller should look like

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Foo foo)
    {
        try
        {
            var _objddContext = new DBContext();
            if (_objdBentityContext != null)
            {
                _objdBentityContext.FoosEntity.Add(foo);
            }
            else
            {
                _objdBentityContext.FoosEntity = new FoosEntity();
                _objdBentityContext.FoosEntity.Add(foo);
            }

            _objdBentityContext.FoosEntity.SaveChanges()

            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

you should have and DBContext class holding and relating all the entities
and that's the class you will initialize and save the foo data with.
You can checkout this link below

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/CodeFirst/index.html

let me know how you fare....keep at it...you will win....